# How should i pass the value for derived class?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming. My below javascript code is not rendering me the value of area as 4 because i didn't declare the required value for the same.Someone please tell me where should i declare the value for height and width?

```js
class polygon {
    constructor(){
        this.name= "polygon";
        
    }
}

var object= new polygon();
console.log(object.name);

class square extends polygon {
    constructor(length) {

      super(length,length);
      
      this.name = 'Square';
     }
  
    get area() {
      return this.height * this.width;
    }
  
    set area(value) {
      this.value = area;
    } 
  }

  var obj= new square();
  var x = new area(2,2);
  console.log(obj.name);
  console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
If you want height and width as separate variables you should include it in polygon and assign the same height and width for square.

```
class polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.name = "polygon";
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

var object = new polygon();
console.log(object.name);

class square extends polygon {
  constructor(length) {
    super(length, length);

    this.name = "Square";
  }

  get area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }

  set area(value) {
    this.value = area;
  }
}

var obj = new square();
var x = new square(2);
console.log(x.name);
console.log(x.area);
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked. after deletion of few line in my code. Is ter any other way to fetch the same output precisely. I mean do there exists other way of coding for the program.

Comment: There are lots of ways to achieve the same result, the question is what problem you are trying to solve and what's the best approach towards achieving a solution. If you have a polygon class with dimensions and if you have a square that extends the polygon class, then I think that design wise this solution is a pretty straightforward approach. Please accept the answer if it works so that the question can be closed. :-)